# How to properly emulate FeignClient responses in JUnit tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-cloud-feign

I am using FeignClient for communication between microservices. I would like to test one microservice **without** running the other, so I need somehow to emulate responses from it. At this time I am mocking feignClient. However is it a right way for emulating FeignClient's responses in this situation?

My FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient(name="shortestPath", url="http://localhost:5000")
public interface GraphFeignClient {

    @PostMapping(path="/short")
    public List<Integer> getShortestPath(@RequestParam("source") int source,
                                         @RequestParam("target") int target,
                                         @RequestBody Graph graph);

}
```

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class GraphJsonApplicationTests {

    @Mock
    GraphFeignClient graphFeignClient;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSavingShortestPath() throws Exception {

        given(graphFeignClient.getShortestPath(anyInt(),anyInt(),any()))
                .willReturn(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)); 

        //...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to write unit tests for feign clients, so the only one way to test is to write integration tests. For integration testing of http clients you may want to use one of two approaches:

1) In case you don't have control over service that you are calling, you could use [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) to mock responses from the service. In that case you will create real bean, and really go through HTTP to mock server. It supports various types of stubs.

2) In case you have control over service that you are calling, you may want to apply Consumer Driven Contracts approach and utilize [Spring cloud contract](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract)

Comment: I use JUnit NOT for testing FeignClient but to test components of my microservice for different responses from other microservice.

Comment: If you are writing unit tests for other components, that call feign clients, then you approach works perfectly. However I would not involve spring beans into testing, you may just use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations. Since if you tests run spring context they are not unit tetsts, but integration tests.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is valuable.

Comment: The feign client is a nontrivial piece of code. It makes sense to unit test nontrivial pieces of code. Your option #1 is, in fact, a unit test of the feign client.